# how to partition a table in mysql with primary key and unique index which is varchar?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I use `mysql 5.6`
I have a table with auto_increment `primary key`, and `unique` column with hexadecimal values.
Unique column is used to be sure that no duplicates are allowed to be inserted into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hexvalue` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `create_date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hexvalue` (`hexvalue`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

when I try to partition it says

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` PARTITION BY HASH ( id + hexvalue) PARTITIONS 10;
ERROR 1491 (HY000): The PARTITION function returns the wrong type
```

As `hexvalue` is `varchar` it could not return me an integer value, when i try to convert the hexadecimal value to decimal using `CONV()` function  it says

```
The patition function is not allowed
```

P.s:-I also checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html

Can I get a hack to partition this table?

Answer (score 0):

First, I must question your need to `PARTITION` the table.  Second, I must point out that I have heard of no useful case for `HASH` partitioning.

If you have a `UNIQUE` column, it should probably be made the `PRIMARY KEY` instead of an artificial `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  OK, you will argue (validly) that it is "long".  If it is truly hex, then pack it into binary and use `BINARY(16)`.  Now it is only 16 bytes, not 32; that's closer to the 4 bytes of an `INT`.  See `HEX()` and `UNHEX()`.

Since you seem to have no other secondary keys, the size of the PK does not matter for that purpose.  Perhaps you reference the `id` from other tables, and they would have to change to `BINARY(16)`?

Is there nothing else in this table, other than the 3 columns?  Seems strange.  I ask because *often* proper schema advice needs to know more about the table, its columns, the `SELECTs`, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply
I want to partition the table because it is filling up my  disk hence if i  partition it i can spread it among different disks.

I used hash partition because through which i can distribute rows into all partitions equally and since the values of hexvalue is `varchar` I am forced to go with hash or key partitioning. 

Ya the table schema is just that much  which stores the hex values with their created date into which many rows are inserted and  queried using hexvalues.

Comment: I guess RAID striping is out of the question?  (That is better both for performance and for maintenance than manually distributing files.)

Comment: Every UNIQUE key (including the PK) must include the key you are partitioning on.  Hence the indexes you currently have need a slight change.

Comment: So, you can drop the `id` column?  And `PARTITION BY ... hexvalue`?  And make `hexvalue` the PK?